# Gitlab CI/CD: on-hold job working with delay

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

In a first time, I would like to know if it is possible to make a gitlab CI/CD job "on hold" during a period.
If this period (in seconds/minutes) is exceeded, I want my job to be executed.

In a second time, I would like to be able to run other jobs during this "on hold" period.

My application:

I'm running a pipeline CI/CD.
At the end of my CI/CD pipeline, I have created a job to clean my test data.

I want this job to be "delayed" to let me execute some other jobs, like a quality code job.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> In a second time, I would like to be able to run other jobs during this "on hold" period.

It sounds like you would like to make use of pipeline [`stages`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages).

For example, you could have the two following stages:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - clean-up
```

which defines the order of execution/progression of your pipeline. As you said, you'd like to run the test data clean up job at the very end, so it would be suitable to have it defined as a job in the `clean_up` stage.

Since all jobs of the same stage run in parallel, if in this same stage you have other jobs defined, you can specify a time [delay](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-a-job-after-a-delay):

```yaml
  when: delayed
  start_in: 30 minutes
```

which touches upon your first question:

> I would like to know if it is possible to make a gitlab CI/CD job "on hold" during a period. If this period (in seconds/minutes) is exceeded, I want my job to be executed.

Putting it together, your `.gitlab-ci.yml` could look like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - clean-up

# code-quality, performance-tests, regression-tests
# are jobs belonging to the same stage "test"
code-quality:
  stage: test
  script: run_code_quality_tests

performance-tests:
  stage: test
  script: run_performance_tests

regression-tests:
  stage: test
  script: run_regression_tests

# this job is defined at the same stage as clean-test-data job;
# it will run in parallel as the clean-test-data job
post-test:
  stage: clean-up
  script:
    - run_something

clean-test-data:
  stage: clean-up
  script:
    - run_clean_up_command
  when: delayed
  # clean-test-data job will not start to run before this 30 min time has lapsed
  start_in: 30 minutes
```